# Access router management from VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I'm using a tp-link TL-ER6120 router in order to use a VPN. The LAN is using the IP range 192.168.100.1 - 255, and I have a TP-Link Archer C7 Wireless router (as AP, with DHCP disabled and connected using LAN port) with IP 192.168.100.10.

I'm assigning the VPN clients the IP 192.168.101.1-10, because I can't overlap LAN IPs with VPN IPs.

But when I try to connect to 192.168.100.10 from VPN client the connection doesn't work. I have a web server running with 192.168.100.5 IP, and it works, but with router it just doesn't work.

Why can I connect to a web server but not to the router?

Comment: I'm not overlapping the addresses, the vpn router doesn't allow me to do that

Comment: You're right, I edited the question